# XNA BoundingBox NOT intersecting

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, collision-detection

I'm trying to figure out why my bigger box does NOT contain the smaller box.

I have the following:

```
BoundingBox b = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(soldier.Position.X - 0.3f, soldier.Position.Y, soldier.Position.Z + 0.2f), new Vector3(soldier.Position.X + 0.3f, soldier.Position.Y + 1.8f, soldier.Position.Z - 0.2f));
BoundingBox b2 = new BoundingBox(new Vector3(soldier.Position.X - 0.015f, soldier.Position.Y + 0.01f, soldier.Position.Z + 0.07f), new Vector3(soldier.Position.X + 0.015f, soldier.Position.Y + 0.015f, soldier.Position.Z - 0.055f));
Console.WriteLine(b.Contains(b2));
Console.WriteLine(soldier.Position);

BoundingBoxRenderer.Render(b, GraphicsDevice, cam.View, cam.Projection, Color.Red);
BoundingBoxRenderer.Render(b2, GraphicsDevice, cam.View, cam.Projection, Color.White);
```

And it prints "Disjoint". However, the smaller box (b2) is definitely inside the bigger box (b). Is there a reason it prints disjointed?

[image]
It draws the white box (b2) inside the red box(b) just fine.
However, it prints:

`Disjoint
{X:22.5 Y:0 Z:-21.5}`

Is there something wrong with my bounding boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there something wrong with my bounding boxes?

Yes. Your boxes are inside out.
For all Bounding boxes; 
the min.x must be a lower value that the max.x.
the min.y must be a lower value that the max.y.
the min.z must be a lower value that the max.z.

But for both of your boxes, the min.z is a greater value than the max.z. Since this is opposite of what's required, this will cause your boxes to fail.

> Why does it then appear to render properly?

Perhaps you have an issue with your rendering code that is negating the Z components.